# Prompt to close on new sheet from pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, userform

I often find that with pivot tables i end up with tons of worksheets from new sheets being created via pivot table drill downs. I thought a great macro would be to display a small userform in the upper right corner of all new sheets created from pivot tables allowing the user to easily delete the sheet and return to the pivot table. However, I cant figure out how to trigger the macro. Any ideas? Basically the macro would need to be automatically triggered anytime a new sheet is created from drilling down in a pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With out getting too complex, you are probably looking for something like this...

Under "ThisWorkbook" add the following code:

---

*EDITED*

This was working for me:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Detect_Pivot(Sh) Then
        Sh.Activate
        frmSheetOptions.Show
    End If
End Sub    

Function Detect_Pivot(wsNew As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim bNew As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0
    bNew = True
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each pvt In wsNew.PivotTables
        i = i + 1
        s = Split(pvt.SourceData, "!")
        sName = s(0)
        If wsNew.Name = sName Then
            bNew = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If i > 0 Then Detect_Pivot = bNew
End Function
```

---

Inside the frm you want to display:

```
Private Sub cmdHide_Click()
    frmSheetOptions.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Delete
    frmSheetOptions.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    frmSheetOptions.lblSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't this code fire every time a new worsheet is created though, even if it is not created from a pivot table drill down? Is there any way to only have the event fire from a pivot table's creation of a new sheet

Comment: It would - I edited my answer to include a function "Detect_Pivot" it's simple and seemed to work for me after testing manually creating a sheet, creating a pivottable on the same sheet and then creating a pivottable on a new sheet. It may not work perfectly for what you need but I don't know how else you could possible learn if the worksheet was generated from the automatic pivottable creation.

Comment: Thank for the response - very helpful! I want to now take this and make it work for every workbook, rather than having to add it to "thisworkbook" every time i open a new doc. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that the "Workbook_NewSheet" event requires it to be in the "ThisWorkbook" module. Without manually replacing the code you would have to come up with a new way to trigger this code. I would just export the "ThisWorkbook" class module and import it into the other documents. That's the quickest way to manually do this.

Answer (score 0):

To start an event whenever a new sheet is created, you can use the following example (an answer from Tim Williams). However, I'm not sure how to tell if the new sheet was created from a pivot table. The drill-down might be an event triggered by the pivot table, in which case, maybe you can apply this method to find it. It would take some investigation.

```
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application

Sub Init()
    Set app = Application 'start capturing events
End Sub

Private Sub app_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print "New"
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print "Before close: " & Wb.Name
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print "Open: " & Wb.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any way to only have the event fire from a pivot table's creation of a new sheet and not just creation of any sheet

Comment: I found a resource which suggests checking the SheetType to see if it is "Show". This will separate sheets that a user creates from sheets created by things like a DrillDown. http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-drilldown.html

Comment: I strongly recommend using a debugger to compare a worksheet compared manually vs by a drill down. You may be able to find other differences besides SheetType.

Comment: Thank for the response - very helpful! I want to now take this and make it work for every workbook, rather than having to add it to "thisworkbook" every time i open a new doc. Any ideas?

Comment: This actually caught a mistake I made, the example I used does check when workbooks are added (rather than worksheets). You can use the same method to check for worksheets too